# ViewModel not initializing or problem design with my viewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I've been reading some questions, answers and blogs about MVVM pattern in Android, and I've implemented it in my application.

My application consists of a MainActivity with 3 Tabs. Content of each tab is a fragment.

One of these fragments, is a List of Users stored on Room DB, which is where I've implemented the MVVM (implementing User object, ViewModel, Repository and Adapter with RecycleView).

In this same fragment, I have an "add User" button at the end that leads to a new activity where a formulary is presented to add a new user. In this activity I want to be sure that the full name of user not exists in my DB before saving it.

I was trying to use the same ViewModel to get full UserNames full name, but it seems that ViewModel is never initialized and I dont' know why.

I've read some questions about that viewmodel can't be used in different activities (I use it in MainActivity also in AddUser activity

This is my ViewModel:

```kotlin
class UserViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val allUsersLiveData: LiveData<List<User>>
    private val repository: UserRepository

    init {
        Timber.i("Initializing UserViewModel")
        repository = UserRepository(UserTrackerApplication.database!!.databaseDao())
        allUsersLiveData = repository.getAllUsers()
    }

    fun getAllUsersFullName(): List<String> {

        return allUsersLiveData.value!!.map { it.fullname}
    }
```

And my AddUser activity:

```kotlin
class AddUser : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var userList:List<String>
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAddUserBinding
    private val userViewModel: UserViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_user)
        Timber.i("Add User OnCreate")

        binding = ActivityAddUserBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)


        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    fun addUserClick(v : View){

        //someCode
        val userName = binding.constraintLayoutAddUser.etUserName!!.text.toString()
        if(checkUserExistance(userName)) {
        val text: String = String.format(
                    resources.getString(R.string.repeated_user_name),
                    userName
        Snackbar.make(v, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        {
        else
        {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                UserTrackerApplication.database!!.databaseDao()
                 .insertUser(user)
                 Timber.i("User added!")
        }
        finish()

    }
}
```

Debugging, I see the log `"Initializing UserViewModel"` when the fragment of MainActivity is started, but I can't see it when AddUser activity is called. So it seems it's not initializing correctly.

So the questions:

1. Is this a good approach? I'm making some design mistake?
2. Why the VM isn't initializing?

**EDIT**

I forgot to add this function. Calling userViewModel here is where I get the error:

```kotlin
 private fun checkUserExistance(userName: String): Boolean {
        var result = false
        userList = userViewModel.getAllUsersNames() 

        for (usr in userList)
        {
            if(usr.uppercase() == userName.uppercase())
            {
                result = true
                break
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

I added this on my "onCreate" function and started to work:

```kotlin
 userViewModel.allUsersLiveData.observe(this, Observer<List<User>>{
            it?.let {
                // updates the list.
                Timber.i("Updating User Names")
                userList =userViewModel.getAllUsersNames()
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you take a look at **by viewModels** delegate you will see it's **lazy** it means it will initialize when it is first time accessed

```
@MainThread
public inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> ComponentActivity.viewModels(
    noinline factoryProducer: (() -> Factory)? = null
): Lazy<VM> {
    val factoryPromise = factoryProducer ?: {
        defaultViewModelProviderFactory
    }

    return ViewModelLazy(VM::class, { viewModelStore }, factoryPromise)
}
```

Comment: Thanks you are right, I just forgot to add the function where I use the ViewModel. I've updated the question

Comment: if you returning a livedata from database you need to observe it, you can't use it like this it needs time to read the data and set the value inside livedata.

Comment: I started to observe and now ViewModel seems to initialize correctly. I've done the changes on Edit 2. So, a viewModel always needs an observer to be initialized?

Comment: As I mentioned at my answer it is initializing lazily. When you add observer to your viewModel's variable you are accessing the viewModel so it is initializing. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html read this document for more details.

Comment: Sorry still don't get it. I understand that viewModel is started lazily. But what I still don't understand  is what I added at first edit, this line `userList = userViewModel.getAllUsersNames() ` why doesn't initializes the VM? I mean, is being used for fisrt time so it should initialize here?

Comment: it initializes the VM but room database operations are async so you can't get livedata value immediately. Therefore it returns empty value you first called.